# Generating code when using Netbeans Swing GUI builder

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, designer, gui-builder

Is there a way to get rid of the designer after creating a Swing GUI using the Netbeans GUI builder, without having to copy the source code into a new class?

Comment: It's already there in `Source` view.

Comment: Yes but some of the source code cannot be changed. I know it's possible to just copy the code to a new class but I wonder if there's another way.

Comment: edited my question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the `.java` file of your class in another editor and remove comments like

`//GEN-BEGIN:variables`

`//GEN-END:variables`

These are not displayed by NetBeans editor. Then you can remove the `.form` file with the same name of your class.

Comment: Thanks! That's great, but it would have been nice if this was also possible from within the Netbeans environment.